# Why the text of combobox show the items with property name?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm working on project using WPF. I have a ComboBox that gets filled with items from my database. I'm trying to get the ID of the item that is selected in the ComboBox, It's working the items showing but the text of Combobox showing property name too. That's my code I used to fill ComboBox.

```
using (var Context = new ProfetusModel())
{
    var GetQuestions = Context.Questions.Select(ques => new {Questions=ques.Question1,ID=ques.IdQues }).ToList();
    // CompoQues.ItemsSource = GetQuestions;
    CompoQues.ItemsSource = GetQuestions
    CompoQues.DisplayMemberPath = "Questions";
    CompoQues.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
    CompoQues.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

it's working but showing like this pic

[image: combo box image]

How can I change the formatting of the question displayed in the combo box so that only the text of the question itself is displayed, rather than the leading brace - i.e.,

The text shows "{Questions = What is the name of (text of selected question)... }"

The text should just display "What is the name of (text of selected question)"

Comment: @FrankerZ   Man that's not my question the question is how i can hide the property name form the text of compobox?

Comment: The Combobox seems to use the default implementation of `ToString`. Override it to just return the Questions value or just store the string values in the comboBox.

Comment: @RobinB I'm don't understand What should id do to fix it

Comment: @RobinB OP's using `DisplayMemberPath`, so it shouldn't take the `ToString()` value to display.

Comment: @MahmoudSamy I tested your code an it worked for me.

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with xaml and code that we can use to reproduce it? Create a new project and paste your mcve to see if with it we can reproduce it.

Comment: @GertArnold I know but it's showing the property name and value how i can get the only value

Comment: Have you used SelectedValue="{Binding Questions}" in xaml

Comment: @RackM I Used it and the result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your code to:

```
public struct ComboItem
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

using (var Context = new ProfetusModel())
{
    var GetQuestions = Context.Questions.Select(ques => new ComboItem { Question = ques.Question1, ID = ques.IdQues }).ToList();

    CompoQues.ItemsSource = GetQuestions
    CompoQues.DisplayMemberPath = "Question";
    CompoQues.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
    CompoQues.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```